# remove layer in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am working with OpenLayers. adding vector layer on checkbox click with lat lng. but I am trying to remove that layer with same lat and lng. but not working.

Any help will be appreciated.

```js
var map;
var mapLat = 29.566;
var mapLng = -98.376;

var mapDefaultZoom = 17;

function initialize_map() {
  map = new ol.Map({
    target: "map",
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM({
          url: "https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        })
      })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([mapLng, mapLat]),
      zoom: mapDefaultZoom
    })
  });
}

function add_map_point(action, lat, lng) {

  var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
      features: [new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([parseFloat(lng), parseFloat(lat)], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),
      })]
    }),
    style: new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Icon({
        anchor: [0.5, 0.5],
        anchorXUnits: "fraction",
        anchorYUnits: "fraction",
        src: "https://img.icons8.com/officexs/16/000000/filled-flag.png"
      })
    })
  });

  if (action === 1) {
    map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
  } else {
    map.removeLayer(vectorLayer);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you calling `add_map_point()` function and that function always creating new instance of `vectorLayer`. Now when you are removing layer, so again it create new instance but that not added in you map.

So instead of doing this define `vectorLayer` once time and when your `checkbox` value changes, based on checkbox value apply your condition for adding/removing layer.

You can remove layer by two way :-

1. One way you can directly pass `vectorLayer` as you defined in first.

   ```js
   map.removeLayer(vectorLayer);
   ```
2. Second way you can set name of your `vector-layer` and after that you can remove the by getting vector layer name.

   ```js
   map.getLayers().forEach(layer => {
     if (layer.get('name') && layer.get('name') == 'flag_vectorLayer'){
         map.removeLayer(layer)
     }
   });
   ```

Please below working code snippet.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```js
var map,
  mapLat = 22.719568,
  mapLng = 75.857727,
  mapDefaultZoom = 17,
  vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
      features: [new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([75.85734861628751, 22.72062520082595], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),
      })]
    }),
    style: new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Icon({
        anchor: [0.5, 0.5],
        anchorXUnits: "fraction",
        anchorYUnits: "fraction",
        src: "//img.icons8.com/officexs/16/000000/filled-flag.png"
      })
    })
  });

vectorLayer.set('name', 'flag_vectorLayer');

map = new ol.Map({
  target: "map",
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM({
        url: "//a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      })
    })
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([mapLng, mapLat]),
    zoom: mapDefaultZoom
  })
});

function add_map_point(evt) {
  if (evt.checked) {
    map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
  } else {
    map.removeLayer(vectorLayer);
  }
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">

<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<title>OpenLayers example</title>
<div><input type="checkbox" onchange="add_map_point(this)" />Add/Remove point</div>

<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: really appreciate your help, I have added unique layer name and removed by that layer name.